# Parse a stringified JSON containing a stringified array

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I've come across something I don't entirely understand and cannot solve however I try.

Say I have an object:

```
const jsonExample = {
    textToReplace: 'My text',
    arrayToReplace: 'My array: ${arrayParam}',
};
```

And I need to stringify this object in order to replace the `arrayParam`:

```
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
const stringifiedJson = JSON.stringify(jsonExample).replace('${arrayParam}', JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

And then I need to parse it back to an object, and get my array back:

```
const newJson = JSON.parse(stringifiedJson);
```

But I get a SyntaxError at the beginning of the stringified array. Is there something I'm missing?

I know it's a rather convoluted way of doing things, but in my real problem I have an iterative replacing method which, up until now, only dealt with strings, but I need it to also replace arrays.

Thanks!

Edit: the error is:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 57`

Comment: May you please share the error as well

Comment: "Say I have a JSON" — that is an **object**, not JSON. JSON is when you get from `JSON.stringify`. See http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Doing a find & replace on a string of JSON sounds like an excellent way to break it. Loop over the properties of the object and replace the values one at a time instead.

Comment: I would do it some other way, but I do need a specific method, which usually takes strings and does the replacing, to take this object as well (and I cannot modify said method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.replace()` you're adding the string `[\"foo\",\"bar\"]` to your stringified object:

```
"{\"textToReplace\":\"My text\",\"arrayToReplace\":\"My array: [\"foo\",\"bar\"]\"}"
```

Above the `\"My array: [\"` is interpreted as the value for `"arrayToReplace"` when parsed. So, the following `f` is interpreted as token and not part of your string value, resulting in your error.

You can instead use the [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) function for `JSON.stringify()` to parse your string first and then the entire object.

See example below:

```js
const jsonExample = {
    textToReplace: 'My text',
    arrayToReplace: 'My array: ${arrayParam}',
};

const myArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
const stringifiedJson = JSON.stringify(jsonExample, (key, val) =>{
  return typeof val === "string"
    ? val.replace('${arrayParam}', JSON.stringify(myArray))
    : val;
});

const newJson = JSON.parse(stringifiedJson);
console.log(newJson);
```